# What is the difference between Math.min() and Math.max() ? In Javascript

Tags: javascript, computer-science

when you execute Math.min(), you will get (Infinity) and when you execute Math.max(), you will get (-Infinity).

by this result for sure if you compare Math.max() > Math.min() you will get false.

why Math.max() return - infinity and Math.min return infinity? it doesn't make sense

why that ?

Comment: Because -infinity is less than infinity? Not sure if I fully understand your question...

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question at all.

Comment: Math.min() and Math.max() are trying to compare (from an array for example), maximum and minimum result... so if you **DON'T** compare with anithing Math.min will give you Infinity because is higher number to compare, so first comparation always will be minimum result.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.min([value1[, value2[, ...]]])
```

returns the lowest integer.

```
Math.max([value1[, value2[, ...]]])
```

returns the highest integer.

Answer (score -4):

Its because (-Infinity) is always less then